# Probability of Integer Solutions with Repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

Let $a+b+c+d+e=30$, where there are non-negative integer solutions. What is the probability $a=5$.

For the solution with no restriction total possibilities are $34C30$. Now let $a=5$, so we get $b+c+d+e=25$. Total number of possibilities now are $28C25$. So probability is $\frac{28C25}{34C30}$. However, I am pretty sure this is wrong as I don't think I can take the probability like this using unordered selection with repetition. Any help ? : )

Comment: More detail is needed. Where does probability enter into this?  Are you saying that each ordered selection is equally probable?  Each unordered selection?  Are you saying that you put $30$ balls into $5$ bins uniformly at random and $a$ is the number in the first bin?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu If I choose a non-negative integer solution to the equation $a+b+c+d+e=30$ uniformly at random, what is the probability that I end up with $a=6$. This is the question.

Comment: Be precise.  You take the list of *ordered* $5-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $30$, you count those (Stars and Bars) and then you count those that begin with $5$ (or is it $6$?) and compute the ratio, right?  Your post mentions *unordered* selections but that's irrelevant, right?

Comment: @lulu Yes the correct question is what I put in the comments. This is where I am confused because I thought the number of non-negative integer solutions to an equation in that form is $n+r-1Cr$ so would be $30+5-1C30$ = $34C30$. Are you saying this is incorrect ?

Comment: So it's $a=6$ then, not $5$ as in your post?

Comment: @lulu Sorry, it is $5$!!!

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Don't leave critical information in the comments.  That said, the Stars and Bars computation is the correct approach to the question I think you are asking.

Comment: To stress:  it is very unusual to take the Stars and Bars solutions as equally probable.  Nothing impossible about it...makes perfect sense mathematically.  But it's hard to see what physical problem that corresponds to.  Throwing balls into distinct bins yields a very different distribution.

Comment: @lulu Okay, so my answer is incorrect because I shouldn’t really be using stars and bars for probabilities ?

Comment: Again, it depends what is being asked.  If, as you claim, you are assuming that each eligible $5-$tuple is equally probable, then your computation is correct.  But this is not at all the same as the parallel balls into bins problem.

Comment: @lulu yes if I choose a non negative integer solution to the equation $a+b+c+d+e=30$, what is the probability $a=5$?. So my answer is correct then just to finally confirm ?

Comment: Yes, though I still suspect that you meant to ask something else.  After all, your post still refers to *unordered* selections, which seem to have no connection to the problem.

Comment: @lulu no what I posted in my comment just before the one I am replying to is the exact wording of the question. I was paraphrasing which caused the confusion.

Comment: Again, don't leave important information in the comments.  Edit your question to include all the relevant information.

Comment: @lulu okay I will later. Thanks for your help though confirming my solution